# one-to-many relationship ios swift 3

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

I'm new in iOS programming, I'm trying to make todo app, so I need help. I'm trying to add one-to-many relationship, but returns error:

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Here my save func code, creating item and trying to manage relationship with list:

```
// Save item action
@IBAction func save(_ sender:UIBarButtonItem){

    if let appDelegate = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate) {
        item = Item(context: appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext)

        item.itemName = (nameTextField.text)!

        // Set relationship
        item.list = list

        appDelegate.saveContext()
    }

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Which line of code is actually causing the error? Is there any error message in the console?

Comment: this one: item.list = list

error: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException